# uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException' - this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key buttonPressed

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8, xib

I am creting my first IOS app. and am stuck with this error. I knew it is asked many times but i don't find my answer or may be not understand those answer as i am complete beginner in ios.
Here is my viewController file code.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var showLabelText: UILabel!
    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let title = sender.title(for: .normal)!
        showLabelText.text = "I Am \(title)"
    }

}
```

I tried by "resetting content and settings" but that doesn't helped.

Please help me to solve this problem. It will encourage me to learn IOS. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Press ⇧⌘F, type `buttonPressed` (with  ↩) and check all search results which are related to Interface Builder. Make sure that the connection is made to the proper class and proper action.

Comment: You need to show the exact error message. But I guess that you have linked your button to `func buttonPressed()` vs `func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton)`. Delete your connection to the method in InterfaceBuilder, and redo it?

Answer (score 0):

In your storyboard, make sure that your IBAction is properly connected with the button that triggers it. It's possible that you modified the IBAction (changed the name, maybe?) and your storyboard no longer knows what you're talking about.